# AddTextChangedListener in mono for android

Tags: listview, xamarin.android, filtering, textchanged

I have a database that I'm using to populate a listview. Above this listview there is an edittext where the user searches for an item in the listview. Based on the input, I want the listview to be refined and filtered to include only those items that are similar to the input. This is straightforward in java but difficult in mono for android by xamarin. Here is my onCreate() method where the databse populates the listview.

```
string[] categories;
protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
{
    base.OnCreate (bundle);
    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.b);
    var destPath = Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "DDxDDB"); 
    System.IO.Stream source = Assets.Open("DDxDDB");
    var dest = System.IO.File.Create (destPath);
    source.CopyTo (dest); 
    var sql = "SELECT _id FROM Sx;";
    var conn = new SqliteConnection ("Data Source=" + destPath.ToString());
    conn.Open ();
    var cmd = conn.CreateCommand ();
    cmd.CommandText = sql;
    SqliteDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader ();
    List<string> categ = new List<string>();
    while (reader.Read()) 
    {
        categ.Add(reader.GetString(0));
    }
    categories = categ.ToArray();
    ArrayAdapter<string> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, Resource.Layout.Main, categories);
    ListView listView = (ListView) FindViewById(Resource.Id.listView1);
    listView.Adapter = dataAdapter; 
    listView.TextFilterEnabled = true;
    EditText myFilter = (EditText)FindViewById(Resource.Id.myFilter);
    myFilter.AddTextChangedListener(New MyTextWatcher);    
}
```

This is the class that I also include in this activity, but I don't know what code to add to the methods to cause my filtering of the listview.

```
public class MyTextWatcher: Java.Lang.Object, ITextWatcher
{
    public void AfterTextChanged(IEditable s) {}
    public void BeforeTextChanged(Java.Lang.ICharSequence arg0, int start, int count, int after) {}
    public void OnTextChanged(Java.Lang.ICharSequence arg0, int start, int before, int count) {}
}
```

Comment: How did you go around doing it in Android? Maybe post the equivalent code of what you are doing there, then it will be easier for me to quickly guide you to how to do it on Mono for Android.

Comment: This was the example I had been using. My difficulty is that methods can be defined inside other methods in java but not c#. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5311032/filter-text-from-listview

Answer (score 6):

As aaronmix says `EditText` has three events which you can use instead of having to implement an `ITextWatcher` class.

So you can attach an `EventHandler` to `AfterTextChanged` and get the `Editable` from the arguments of the `Event`:

```
var editText = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.MyEditText);
editText.AfterTextChanged += (sender, args) =>
{
    //do your stuff in here
    //args.Editable is the equivalent of the `s` argument from Java
    //afterTextChanged(Editable s)
};
```

Answer (score 3):

In Mono for Android's implementaion, `EditText` already has three events `TextChanged`, `AfterTextChanged` and `BeforeTextChanged`, so you can just add delegates to each of those.

Answer (score 0):

Yes thank you to both of you for the help. I am doing something similar to that and it works great. Here it is:

```
string[] categories;

protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
{
    base.OnCreate (bundle);
    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.b);
    var destPath = Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "DDxDDB"); 
    System.IO.Stream source = Assets.Open("DDxDDB");
    var dest = System.IO.File.Create (destPath);
    source.CopyTo (dest); 
    var sql = "SELECT _id FROM Sx;";
    var conn = new SqliteConnection ("Data Source=" + destPath.ToString());
    conn.Open ();
    var cmd = conn.CreateCommand ();
    cmd.CommandText = sql;
    SqliteDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader ();
    List<string> categ = new List<string>();
    while (reader.Read()) 
    {
        categ.Add(reader.GetString(0));
    }
    categories = categ.ToArray();
    ArrayAdapter<string> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, Resource.Layout.Main, categories);
    ListView listView = (ListView) FindViewById(Resource.Id.listView1);
    listView.Adapter = dataAdapter; 
    listView.TextFilterEnabled = true;
    EditText myFilter = (EditText)FindViewById(Resource.Id.myFilter);
    myFilter.TextChanged += new EventHandler<TextChangedEventArgs>(OnTextChange);
}

public void OnTextChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
{           
    EditText myFilter = (EditText)FindViewById(Resource.Id.myFilter);
    string val = myFilter.Text.ToString();
    List<string> categ2 = new List<string>();
    foreach (string value in categories) 
    {
        if (value.IndexOf(val, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) != -1)
        {
            categ2.Add(value);
        }
    }
    string[] categories2 = categ2.ToArray();
    ArrayAdapter<string> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, Resource.Layout.Main, categories2);
    ListView listView = (ListView) FindViewById(Resource.Id.listView1);
    listView.Adapter = dataAdapter; 
    listView.TextFilterEnabled = true;
}
```