# Twitter-like Android Autocomplete Textview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-widget

I want to implement a twitter-like Android Autocomplete Listview but the existing Android Auto-complete Textview isn't good with adding images to the autocomplete suggestions. I need to download images and strings from the server and add to the suggestion box. I have added a reference image.
Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Have you done any thing so far?

Comment: I am going to post that in a few minutes.

Comment: http://pastie.org/3236646 The TextView Activity Code

Comment: http://pastie.org/3236655 The CustomAdapter Code. We are trying to download the data and the images but the suggestions don't stay!

Comment: @ManoharPerepa We wrote a custom listview ourselves

Answer (score 1):

- Create filterable listView as shown in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2718202/custom-filtering-in-android-using-arrayadapter).
- Extend the EditText to create control which on click opens for result new activity with editText control and the filterable listview bellow it.
- Add onTextChangedListener on the edit text to filter the view.
- Add onItemSelected Listener to the listView. When item is selected close the dialog and return the selected object
- on Dialog cancel check if already entered value match value from the list if yes return the object if not return null.

Hope this helps.