# filtering ListView. Getting right values but cant display them

Tags: java, android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I have a ListView with an ArrayAdpater. I try to filter the ListView and my ArrayAdpater is getting the right values. But I can't display them, because the ListView always throws an ArrayOutOfBounds Exception.
For Example my List contains 16 names. 3 of them start with the letter "l".
My ItemsArray in the Adapter contains only the 3 names but it does not stop trying to populate the list and i get an ArrayOutOfBounds Exception.

I commented the Code where the Exception occurs.

```
class FriendListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Friend> implements Filterable {

private ArrayList<Friend> items;
ArrayList<Friend> mOriginalValues; // Original Values

public FriendListAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<Friend> items) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, items);
        this.items = items;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


        View v = convertView;
        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.addfriendtoeventlistrow, null);
        }
        final Friend o = items.get(position); //<-- Here comes the ArrayOutOfBounds because position > array.size()
        if (o != null) {
                TextView tt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.friendname);
                ImageView icon = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.friendprofileimage);
                final CheckBox selectBox = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.selectFriend);
                selectBox.setClickable(false);
                selectBox.setFocusable(false);
                selectBox.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);



         if(selectBox != null){
                    selectBox.setChecked(o.getSelected());
                if(icon != null){
                    icon.setImageDrawable(o.getFriendProfileImage());
                if (tt != null) {
                      tt.setText(o.getFriendName());                            }

        }
        }
        }
        return v;

}

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    Filter filter = new Filter() {

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,FilterResults results) {
            items = (ArrayList<Friend>) results.values; // has the filtered values
            for(int i=0;i<items.size();i++){
            Log.i("FilteredItems",items.get(i).getFriendName());
            }

            notifyDataSetChanged();  // notifies the data with new filtered values

        }

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();        // Holds the results of a filtering operation in values
            ArrayList<Friend> FilteredArrList = new ArrayList<Friend>();

            if (mOriginalValues == null) {
                mOriginalValues = new ArrayList<Friend>(items); // saves the original data in mOriginalValues
            }

            /********
             * 
             *  If constraint(CharSequence that is received) is null returns the mOriginalValues(Original) values
             *  else does the Filtering and returns FilteredArrList(Filtered)  
             *
             ********/
            if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {

                // set the Original result to return  
                results.count = mOriginalValues.size();
                results.values = mOriginalValues;
            } else {
                constraint = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
                for (int i = 0; i < mOriginalValues.size(); i++) {


                    String data = mOriginalValues.get(i).getFriendName();
                    if (data.toLowerCase().startsWith(constraint.toString())) {
                        FilteredArrList.add(mOriginalValues.get(i));
                    }
                }
                // set the Filtered result to return
                results.count = FilteredArrList.size();
                results.values = FilteredArrList;

                for(int i=0;i<FilteredArrList.size();i++){
                    Log.i("FilteredArrList",FilteredArrList.get(i).getFriendName());
                    }
            }


            return results;
        }
    };
    return filter;
}
```

This is how I create the Adapter and the List

```
            m_friends = new ArrayList<Friend>();
        this.m_adapter = new FriendListAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.addfriendtoeventlistrow, m_friends);
        friendList = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.addfriendsList);
        friendList.setAdapter(m_adapter);
```

This is the Exception

```
> 01-19 10:59:22.719: E/AndroidRuntime(3138): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-19 10:59:22.719: E/AndroidRuntime(3138): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 3, size is 3
01-19 10:59:22.719: E/AndroidRuntime(3138):     at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:251)
01-19 10:59:22.719: E/AndroidRuntime(3138):     at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:304)
01-19 10:59:22.719: E/AndroidRuntime(3138):     at com.flashback.flashbackapp.FriendListAdapter.getView(AddFriendsToEventDialog.java:252)
01-19 10:59:22.719: E/AndroidRuntime(3138):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2019)
01-19 10:59:22.719: E/AndroidRuntime(3138):     at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1244)
01-19 10:59:22.719: E/AndroidRuntime(3138):     at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1155)
01-19 10:59:22.719: E/AndroidRuntime(3138):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12881)
01-19 10:59:22.719: E/AndroidRuntime(3138):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4802)
01-19 10:59:22.719: E/AndroidRuntime(3138):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1385)
01-19 10:59:22.719: E/AndroidRuntime(3138):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:676)
01-19 10:59:22.719: E/AndroidRuntime(3138):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:557)
01-19 10:59:22.719: E/AndroidRuntime(3138):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12881)
01-19 10:59:22.719: E/AndroidRuntime(3138):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4802)
01-19 10:59:22.719: E/AndroidRuntime(3138):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:297)
01-19 10:59:22.719: E/AndroidRuntime(3138):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12881)
01-19 10:59:22.719: E/AndroidRuntime(3138):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4802)
01-19 10:59:22.719: E/AndroidRuntime(3138):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:297)
01-19 10:59:22.719: E/AndroidRuntime(3138):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12881)
01-19 10:59:22.719: E/AndroidRuntime(3138):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4802)
01-19 10:59:22.719: E/AndroidRuntime(3138):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:297)
01-19 10:59:22.719: E/AndroidRuntime(3138):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12881)
01-19 10:59:22.719: E/AndroidRuntime(3138):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4802)
01-19 10:59:22.719: E/AndroidRuntime(3138):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:297)
01-19 10:59:22.719: E/AndroidRuntime(3138):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2111)
01-19 10:59:22.719: E/AndroidRuntime(3138):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12881)
01-19 10:59:22.719: E/AndroidRuntime(3138):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1064)
01-19 10:59:22.719: E/AndroidRuntime(3138):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2442)
01-19 10:59:22.719: E/AndroidRuntime(3138):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-19 10:59:22.719: E/AndroidRuntime(3138):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-19 10:59:22.719: E/AndroidRuntime(3138):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4441)
01-19 10:59:22.719: E/AndroidRuntime(3138):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-19 10:59:22.719: E/AndroidRuntime(3138):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-19 10:59:22.719: E/AndroidRuntime(3138):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
01-19 10:59:22.719: E/AndroidRuntime(3138):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
01-19 10:59:22.719: E/AndroidRuntime(3138):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Try the links for custom filtering [custom filtering using arrayadapter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2718202/custom-filtering-in-android-using-arrayadapter) http://www.androidhive.info/2012/09/android-adding-search-functionality-to-listview/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8678198/726863

Comment: Where is `com.flashback.flashbackapp.FriendListAdapter.getView(AddFriendsToEventDialog.java:252)` ?