# Android Search Filter with custom listview, custom adapter and custom object

Tags: android

I'm trying to implement a search filter for my code however, I'm having some problem at the moment. The error that I'm receiving is:

> ArrayList cannot be cast to CustomApapter

I know that this error is happening because I am using List within my CustomAdapter instead of ArrayList. The problem is that I don't know how to fix it to get it to work properly.

***CustomAdapter***

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Filter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Records> {

    Context context;
    int layoutResourceId;
    List<Records> data;

    private Filter fRecords;

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, List<Records> data) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        View row = convertView;
        DataHolder holder = null;

        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

            holder = new DataHolder();
            holder.dataName = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.dataName);
            holder.dataType = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.dataType);

            row.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (DataHolder)row.getTag();
        }

        Records records = data.get(position);
        holder.dataName.setText(records.getName());
        holder.dataType.setText(records.getType());

        return row;
    }

    private class RecordFilter extends Filter {

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

            //Implement filter logic
            if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {
                //No need for filter
                results.values = data;
                results.count = data.size();
            } else {
                //Need Filter
                List<Records> fRecords = new ArrayList<Records>();

                for (Records s : data) {
                    if (s.getName().toUpperCase().contains(constraint.toString().toUpperCase())) {
                        fRecords.add(s);
                    }
                }

                results.values = fRecords;
                results.count = fRecords.size();
            }
            return results;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
                FilterResults results) {
            //inform the adapter about the new list
            if (results.count == 0) {
                notifyDataSetInvalidated();
            } else {
                data = (List<Records>) results.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

        }

    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        if (fRecords == null) {
            fRecords = new RecordFilter();
        }

        return fRecords;
    }

    static class DataHolder {
        TextView dataName;
        TextView dataType;
    }

}
```

***DataLayout***

```
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class DataLayout extends Activity {
    private RecordsDataSource datasource;

    Button btnDataCancel;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.data_layout);       

        datasource = new RecordsDataSource(this);
        datasource.open();

        final List<Records> values = datasource.getNameType();

        //use the SimpleCursorAdapter to show the
        //elements in a ListView
        //ArrayAdapter<Records> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Records>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
        //setListAdapter(adapter);


        CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, R.layout.data_layout_listview, values);
        final ListView listView1 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);

        listView1.setAdapter(adapter);


        Button btnDataCancel = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnDataCancel);

        //Cancel Button
        btnDataCancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                //Starting a new Intent
                Intent goMain = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);

                startActivity(goMain);
                finish();
            }
        });

        //ListView onClick
        listView1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Object o = listView1.getItemAtPosition(position);
                Records str =(Records)o;

                Intent rData = new Intent(DataLayout.this, RecordView.class);
                rData.putExtra("DataId", String.valueOf(str.getId()));
                DataLayout.this.startActivity(rData);
                //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), str.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        //Filter Text
        EditText edtFilter = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtFilter);

        edtFilter.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                    int count) {
                System.out.println("Text [" + s + "]");
                ((CustomAdapter) values).getFilter().filter(s.toString());

            }

        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        datasource.open();
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        datasource.close();
        super.onPause();
    }
}
```

Edit1:
@alexei burmistrov
Thank you for your help, it now throws a different error. Below is the log:

```
05-20 22:54:39.275: E/AndroidRuntime(526): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-20 22:54:39.275: E/AndroidRuntime(526): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 3, size is 3
05-20 22:54:39.275: E/AndroidRuntime(526):  at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
05-20 22:54:39.275: E/AndroidRuntime(526):  at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
05-20 22:54:39.275: E/AndroidRuntime(526):  at com.pbear.drillmaster.CustomAdapter.getView(CustomAdapter.java:69)
05-20 22:54:39.275: E/AndroidRuntime(526):  at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1949)
05-20 22:54:39.275: E/AndroidRuntime(526):  at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1228)
05-20 22:54:39.275: E/AndroidRuntime(526):  at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1139)
05-20 22:54:39.275: E/AndroidRuntime(526):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:10828)
05-20 22:54:39.275: E/AndroidRuntime(526):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4351)
05-20 22:54:39.275: E/AndroidRuntime(526):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1284)
05-20 22:54:39.275: E/AndroidRuntime(526):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:613)
05-20 22:54:39.275: E/AndroidRuntime(526):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:519)
05-20 22:54:39.275: E/AndroidRuntime(526):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:10828)
05-20 22:54:39.275: E/AndroidRuntime(526):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4351)
05-20 22:54:39.275: E/AndroidRuntime(526):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:267)
05-20 22:54:39.275: E/AndroidRuntime(526):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:10828)
05-20 22:54:39.275: E/AndroidRuntime(526):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4351)
05-20 22:54:39.275: E/AndroidRuntime(526):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1284)
05-20 22:54:39.275: E/AndroidRuntime(526):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:613)
05-20 22:54:39.275: E/AndroidRuntime(526):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:519)
05-20 22:54:39.275: E/AndroidRuntime(526):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:10828)
05-20 22:54:39.275: E/AndroidRuntime(526):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4351)
05-20 22:54:39.275: E/AndroidRuntime(526):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:267)
05-20 22:54:39.275: E/AndroidRuntime(526):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:1889)
05-20 22:54:39.275: E/AndroidRuntime(526):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:10828)
05-20 22:54:39.275: E/AndroidRuntime(526):  at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:938)
05-20 22:54:39.275: E/AndroidRuntime(526):  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:2040)
05-20 22:54:39.275: E/AndroidRuntime(526):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-20 22:54:39.275: E/AndroidRuntime(526):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
05-20 22:54:39.275: E/AndroidRuntime(526):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4123)
05-20 22:54:39.275: E/AndroidRuntime(526):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-20 22:54:39.275: E/AndroidRuntime(526):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
05-20 22:54:39.275: E/AndroidRuntime(526):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
05-20 22:54:39.275: E/AndroidRuntime(526):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
05-20 22:54:39.275: E/AndroidRuntime(526):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Edit2:
Thanks to alexei burmistrov for clearing up a lot of the concept with filtering. I have finally got it working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call getFilter().filter(...) not on your datasource (values) but as

adapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString();

No typecast needed.

When filtering data, do not ever modify original dataset, in publishResults modify its internal copy using adapter's getItem, add and clear methods or use a manual copy of data for getView. Also  override getCount to size of this manual copy.

see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2718202/custom-filtering-in-android-using-arrayadapter) as one of the samples using internal data copy.

for the first alternative (most sane to me), in getView use getItem to acquire Record not from original dataset but from internal one. Do not override getCount. in publishResults use clear and then add (addAll) to copy filtered data.

for the second alternative, copy data in constructor to, say, filteredData and use filteredData in getView() getCount() and publishResults instead of data. Leave performFiltering as is

Comment: So do you mean to use the **adapter** from the following code instead?
 
`CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, R.layout.data_layout_listview, values);`

Comment: Yes, save it in the activity or get through listview.getAdapter()

Comment: Got that working, but now I got an size error withing my **getView** in **CustomAdapter**

Comment: hmm. Offtopic: it seems that while filtering you permanently change your original dataset... this would not work.

Comment: I've been going through alot of examples that I've found on the website and this is the one that I think it's the most closed thing that I can find [link](http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2012/10/android-listview-custom-filter-and.html)

Comment: I'm very new to android and this is my first program that I've created to learn the language....I do thank you for helping me out.

Comment: Look, in publishResults you are modifying you original list, the only full source of your data. How could you get filtered out values back without recreating adapter? I am no guru too, but this is a serious question to the tut creator... By the way, does this stacktrace appear in onCreate or when filtering is applied?

Comment: This error only happens when it is filtering. When it first load with 0 filtering, there's no error within the system. 
I'm looking at the code as we speak and yes you do point out a good point. In his tutorial, he later created a new array to store the original list, which you can find the link [here](http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2013/01/android-listview-filterable.html)

Comment: This is the source of IndexOutOfBounds: internally copied full array is not used, so it has full length. You have not overriden getCount() so ArrayAdapter uses this value to determine count. Then you shrink your original "data" and when getView is trying to getView from outside it you get IndexOutOfBounds. I will extend the answer...

Comment: Thank you so much. I'll be waiting for the extended answer.
What you've mentioned do make sense and I'm also researching through google while waiting.

Comment: Hey, I finally got it working. After having a good thought about what you've mentioned up above, and some googling around and found [this](http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/07/android-listview-custom-layout-filter.html) website and following it carefully. I got it working!!
 Also, since I've got it working, what you've said about deleting the original data seems to be clear. I'll continue my work on it right now.
 Once again, thank you so much for helping