# Filtering by using getFilter() in an adapter, fills list with filtered data

Tags: android, listadapter

I have an adapter like below and i getFilter method to filter data in an listview. It works but after filtered, there are only filtered data. I mean for example when i filtered usind "test1" keyword, there there are test1,test12,test13 ... , when i delete last word "test"
i expect filter to load whole data again.

how can i solve this propblem.

```
search.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            listAdapter.getFilter().filter(s);
            Log.v("textchanged",s.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
            int after) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });


 private class BranchListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<BranchViewModel>{

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<BranchViewModel> itemList;
    private int layoutResources;

    public BranchListAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,ArrayList<BranchViewModel> objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);

        this.context = context;
        this.itemList = objects;
        this.layoutResources = textViewResourceId;

    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if(convertView == null){
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(this.context).inflate(this.layoutResources, null);
        }

        ATextView aTextView =(ATextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.havalePaymentTypeItemText);
        aTextView.setText(itemList.get(position).getBranchCode() +"-"+ itemList.get(position).getBranchName());

        return convertView;

    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        Filter filter = new Filter() {

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,FilterResults results) {
            Log.println(Log.INFO, "Results", "FOUND");
            itemList.clear();
            itemList.addAll((ArrayList<BranchViewModel>) results.values);
            Log.e("VALUES","in publish : "+ String.valueOf(itemList.size()));
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
            ArrayList<BranchViewModel> FilteredBranchViewModel = new ArrayList<BranchViewModel>();

            constraint = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();

            for (int i = 0; i < itemList.size(); i++) {
            String dataNames = itemList.get(i).getBranchName();
            String dataId = itemList.get(i).getBranchCode();

            if (dataNames.toLowerCase().startsWith(constraint.toString()) | dataId.toLowerCase().startsWith(constraint.toString()))  {
                FilteredBranchViewModel.add(itemList.get(i));
            }
            }

            results.count = FilteredBranchViewModel.size();
            results.values = FilteredBranchViewModel;
            Log.e("VALUES","in filter : "+ String.valueOf(results.count));

            return results;
        }
        };

        return filter;    
    }
```

Comment: probably you should keep a copy of the original dataset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the source for `ArrayAdapter.ArrayFilter`. You will see that they make a copy of the original data in `performFiltering(CharSequence)`.

Snippet:

```
if (mOriginalValues == null) {
    synchronized (mLock) {
        mOriginalValues = new ArrayList<T>(mObjects);
    }
}

if (prefix == null || prefix.length() == 0) {
    ArrayList<T> list;
    synchronized (mLock) {
        list = new ArrayList<T>(mOriginalValues);
    }
}
results.values = list;
results.count = list.size();
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2718202/custom-filtering-in-android-using-arrayadapter