# android app to view contact address in listview and searching using listadapter.getfilter().filter(s);

Tags: android, android-listview

Am working on the android app to get all contact address saved on the mobile to view it using multiple selection listview to allow user choose the contacts he want

am implementing in the activity textwatcher to listening for the edit text

but the problem am still faceing, i can't filter the contact using getfilter().filter(s)
after a lot of searching, only this solution worked for me 
[Custom filtering in Android using ArrayAdapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2718202/custom-filtering-in-android-using-arrayadapter)

but after am clearing the editText the list data are gone

any full solution please??

Comment: use CursorAdapter.setFilterQueryProvider

Comment: @pskink am trying it too, but it's didn't work well with custom adapter

Comment: use SimpleCursorAdapter, why custom? anyway with custom it works too...

Comment: @pskink cutsom to view name, number and email for every contacts in the list, and i want to allow user check contact using multiple selection listview

Comment: never mind, custom or not, FQP works with them

Comment: @pskink if u have an exmple, u'll help me :)

Comment: just call setFilterQueryProvider and implement FilterQueryProvider interface