# SectionIndexer interface does not update

Tags: android, listview, adapter

I wanted to make a listview with alphabetical adapter so that you can see the letters mapped to each section when fastscrolling. The following works correctly when the listview is initialised. However, if the list changes (e.g. adding or removing rows) the indexer does not seem to update even though a new adapter is created each time. It uses the same set of alphabets as the original list.

```
 private void GenerateListView (final ArrayList<String> listItems) {
        try {
            listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView_browser);

            // generate section index adapter
            AlphabeticalAdapter adapter = new AlphabeticalAdapter(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listItems);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);

            // recall scroll position
            if (_currPos < listItems.size())
                listView.setVerticalScrollbarPosition(_currPos);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

The following is the alphabetical adapter class.

```
public class AlphabeticalAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> implements SectionIndexer
{
    private HashMap<String, Integer> alphaIndexer;
    private String[] sections;

    public AlphabeticalAdapter(Context c, int resource, List<String> data)
    {
        // create ArrayAdapter<String>
        super(c, resource, data);

        // generate HashMap
        alphaIndexer = new HashMap<>();

        // generate index
        for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++)
        {
            // convert first letter of each entry to upper case
            String s = data.get(i).substring(0, 1).toUpperCase();

            // map letter with corresponding index
            if (!alphaIndexer.containsKey(s))
                alphaIndexer.put(s, i);
        }

        // assign set view of keys in the HashMap
        Set<String> sectionLetters = alphaIndexer.keySet();

        // generate list from the set view
        ArrayList<String> sectionList = new ArrayList<>(sectionLetters);

        // sort list alphabetically
        Collections.sort(sectionList);

        // define and populate string array with the letters
        sections = new String[sectionList.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < sectionList.size(); i++)
            sections[i] = sectionList.get(i);
    }
```

Comment: post complete stacktrace (i.e. where exactly do you get that error)

Comment: I got the error when setting a breakpoint at the end of the adapter class and observing the variable. Sorry, it appears I got it fixed somehow 10 minutes ago, yet this problem still stands. So they don't appear to be related.

Answer (score 0):

> See this solution [Code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2726348/2535875).

And to update SectionIndexer using filter or any data change override this method. It's work for me.

```
 @Override
    public void notifyDataSetInvalidated() {
        //write your code 
        super.notifyDataSetInvalidated();
    }
```