# Custom Adapter Not Refreshing after Filter with SearchView - Android-

Tags: java, android, listview, android-arrayadapter

this is my problem:

Im triying to filter a long ListView, precharged with database, with a Custom ArrayAdapter what implements filterable, i set up to filter with an ActionBar SearchView, the deal is when after doing the filter  (debugging I realize it doing well) My list View isn't refreshing the new List (filtered one), here is my code:

**CategoriesActivity.java**

```
public class CategoriesActivity extends Activity implements OnQueryTextListener {

ListView lista;
String datos;
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
List<Categoria> elementos;
ArrayAdapter<Categoria> adaptador;
SharedPreferences settings;
SearchView mSearchView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_categories);
    settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    new CargarListView().execute();
}

public class CargarListView extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(CategoriesActivity.this);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.setMessage("Cargando categorias...");
        pDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        pDialog.setProgress(0);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... Strings) {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        /*Creamos el objeto de HttpClient que nos permitira conectarnos mediante peticiones http*/
        //HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://myurl.com/app/callajax.php");
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://myurl.com/list_category.php");
        /*El objeto HttpPost permite que enviemos una peticion de tipo POST a una URL especificada*/
        String text = "";
        try {
        /*Una vez añadidos los parametros actualizamos la entidad de httppost, esto quiere decir en pocas palabras anexamos los parametros al objeto para que al enviarse al servidor envien los datos que hemos añadido*/
        /*Finalmente ejecutamos enviando la info al server*/
        HttpResponse resp = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity ent = resp.getEntity();/*y obtenemos una respuesta*/

        text = EntityUtils.toString(ent);

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            text = "error";
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            text = "error";
        }

        return text;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if (result != null ) {
            try {
                JSONArray Jarr = new JSONArray(result);
                JSONObject datos = Jarr.getJSONObject(0);
                JSONArray jArray = datos.getJSONArray("data");
                elementos = new ArrayList<Categoria>();
                int sum = 0;
                for(int i=0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                    String titulo = jArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("title");
                    String id = jArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("id");
                    String cantidad = jArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("count");
                    elementos.add(new Categoria(id, titulo, cantidad));
                    sum += Integer.valueOf(cantidad);
                }
                elementos.add(0, new Categoria("1", "En todos", String.valueOf(sum)));
                //Instancia del ListView
                   lista = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);


                //Inicializar el adaptador con la fuente de datos
                adaptador = new CategoriaArrayAdapter(CategoriesActivity.this, elementos);

                //Relacionando la lista con el adaptador
                lista.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
                lista.setAdapter(adaptador);
                lista.setFastScrollEnabled(true);
                lista.setOnItemClickListener( new OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {
                        Categoria Opcion = (Categoria)adaptador.getItem(position);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Categoria: "+Opcion.getTitulo(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Editor edit = settings.edit();
                        edit.putString("PREF_CATEGORY", Opcion.getId());
                        edit.apply();
                        finish();
                    }
                });
            }catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.categories, menu);
    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    mSearchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();
    setupSearchView(searchItem);
    return true;
}

private void setupSearchView(MenuItem searchItem) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    mSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    adaptador.getFilter().filter(newText);
    return false;
}
```

**CategoriesArrayAdapter.java**

```
public class CategoriaArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Categoria> implements Filterable {
List<Categoria> original;
List<Categoria> filtered;
public CategoriaArrayAdapter(Context context, List<Categoria> objects) {
    super(context, 0, objects);
    this.original = objects;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

    //Obteniendo una instancia del inflater
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    //Salvando la referencia del View de la fila
    View listItemView = convertView;

    //Comprobando si el View no existe
    if (null == convertView) {
        //Si no existe, entonces inflarlo con cat_list_view.xml
        listItemView = inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.cat_list_item,
                parent,
                false);
    }

    //Obteniendo instancias de los elementos
    TextView titulo = (TextView)listItemView.findViewById(R.id.txtCat);
    TextView cantidad = (TextView)listItemView.findViewById(R.id.txtCantcat);

    //Obteniendo instancia de la Tarea en la posición actual
    Categoria item = getItem(position);

    titulo.setText(item.getTitulo());
    cantidad.setText("("+item.getCantidad()+")");

    return listItemView;

}

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    Filter filter = new Filter() {

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
            //constraint is the result from text you want to filter against. 
            //objects is your data set you will filter from
            if(constraint != null && original !=null) {
                int length= original.size();
                filtered.clear();
                for (int i = 0; i<length; i++){
                   Locale locale = Locale.getDefault();
                   Categoria item = original.get(i);
                   String data = item.getTitulo();
                   if (data.toLowerCase(locale).contains(constraint.toString())) {
                       filtered.add(item);
                   }
                }
                filterResults.values = filtered;
                filterResults.count = filtered.size();
             }else{
                 filterResults.count = original.size();
                 filterResults.values = original;
             }
             return filterResults;
        }
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            original  = (List<Categoria>) results.values;
            if (results.count > 0) {
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            } else {
                notifyDataSetInvalidated();
            }
        }

    };
    return filter;
}
```

}

Do i missing something??? i really need help with this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on this answer -> [Custom filtering in Android using ArrayAdapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2718202/custom-filtering-in-android-using-arrayadapter?rq=1)
, this is my solution:

```
    @Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    if (filter == null) {
        filter = new ArrayFilter();
    }
    return filter;
}

private class ArrayFilter extends Filter{
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
        FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
        if(constraint != null && constraint.length()> 0) {
            ArrayList<Categoria> values = new ArrayList<Categoria>(original);
            filtered = new ArrayList<Categoria>();
            int length = values.size();
            for (int i = 0; i<length; i++) {
                Locale locale = Locale.getDefault();
                Categoria item = values.get(i);
                String data = item.getTitulo();
                if (data.toLowerCase(locale).contains(constraint.toString())) {
                    filtered.add(item);
                }
            }
            filterResults.values = filtered;
            filterResults.count = filtered.size();
        }else{
            synchronized(this) {
                filterResults.count = original.size();
                filterResults.values = original;
            }
        }
        return filterResults;
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
        data = (List<Categoria>) results.values;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
        clear();
        addAll(data);
        notifyDataSetInvalidated();
    }
}
```

}