# What is the easiest filter method for custom listview adapter?

Tags: android, sqlite, filter, textview, adapter

[image]

I have an EditText and Custom ListView Adapter connected sqllite db. 
I can add, remove and edit records. The next goal is filter the records by EditText.
I wroted this codes but It didn't filtered correctly.

```
private EditText et_search_filter;
private TextWatcher watcher_search_filter;
et_search_filter = (EditText) findViewById(id.et_search_box);
et_search_filter.addTextChangedListener(watcher_search_filter);

watcher_search_filter = new TextWatcher() {
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    adapter.getFilter().filter(s);              
}

public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
}

public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
}
```

};

Here my cursor method:

```
public ArrayList<Item> item_get_all() {
    ArrayList<Item> itemList = new ArrayList<Item>();

    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_ITEMS;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Item dbitems = new Item();
            dbitems.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(items_id))));
            dbitems.setName(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(items_item_name)));
            dbitems.setBrand(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(items_brand)));
            dbitems.setItemType(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(items_type)));
            dbitems.setModel(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(items_model)));
            dbitems.setNote(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(items_note)));
            dbitems.setPurchaseFrom(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(items_purchase_from)));
            dbitems.setPurchasePrice(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(items_price)));
            dbitems.setPurchaseDate(cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(items_purchase_date)));
            itemList.add(dbitems);              
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    db.close();
    return itemList;
}
```

And I called cursor adapter like this:

```
public void getItemList() {     
    ArrayList<Item> itemArray = new ArrayList<Item>();      
    itemArray = db.item_get_all();      
    adapter = new ItemAdapter(this, R.layout.items_row, itemArray);
    ilistViewItems.setAdapter(adapter);                     
}
```

Here are my ItemAdapter.java and Item_row.xml files:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_item_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="@string/nullstr"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="13dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_item_brand"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv_item_name"
        android:text="@string/nullstr"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="#bbbbbb"
        android:textSize="11dp" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_purchase_date"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv_item_name"
        android:text="@string/nullstr"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="#aabbbb"
        android:textSize="11dp" />
</RelativeLayout>

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import db.Item;
public class ItemAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item>{
private ArrayList<Item> items;
private TextView item_name;    
private TextView item_brand;
private TextView item_purchase_date;      

public ItemAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<Item> objects) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
    this.items = objects;

}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.items_row, null);
    }

    item_name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_item_name);    

    item_brand = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_item_brand);
    item_purchase_date = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_purchase_date);       

    item_name.setText(items.get(position).getName());       
    item_brand.setText("[" + items.get(position).getItemType() + "] " + items.get(position).getBrand() + " " + items.get(position).getModel());
    item_purchase_date.setText(items.get(position).getPurchasedDateStr());

    return convertView;
}
```

}

Comment: What type of adapter are you using? What you posted will work for an ArrayAdapter, but not a CursorAdapter.

Comment: It seems CursorAdapter. Datas come from sqldb cursor.

Comment: Ok, post the function that you use to fetch your Cursor and I'll walk you through it. (It's easier when I have a real example.)

Comment: Dear @Sam, I posted my funtions and codes. Thank you

Comment: Great, would you post ItemAdapter and items_row.xml?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Rewrite**

Have you implemented Item's toString() method?

```
public class Item {
    ...

    // Define a method to return a String that describes each Item, preferably unique String
    public String toString() {
        return name + "  " + brand + "  " + model + "  " + type;
    }
}
```

When I use this method with every thing you have posted, the EditText filters the ListView just fine. Let me know if this simple change works for you.

**Efficiency**

I want to point out a few tricks for your existing code to run faster.

Look at your database adapter's get_item_all() method.

- For a new Cursor you only need to call moveToNext(), this will return true while there is valid data to be read.
- IDs in SQliteDatabases are `long` data types. You should change the id in Item from an `int` to a `long` and use Cursor.getLong().
- You search for each column's index for *every* item. Find the indices once and store them locally.

All together, this is more efficient:

```
int idIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(items_id);
int nameIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(items_item_name);
//etc.

while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
    Item dbitems = new Item();

    dbitems.setID(cursor.getLong(idIndex));
    dbitems.setName(cursor.getString(nameIndex));
    ...
    itemList.add(dbitems);              
}
```

Next, look at Item.getView().

- You only need to create one LayoutInflater and store it in the class. I suggest initializing it in your constructor.
- You use findViewById() and `item.get(position)` multiple times every time getView() is called. Whenever the user scrolls the ListView the adapter uses getView() to display each row, you only need to call findViewById() when `convertView` is null.

All together:

Create a variable called `LayoutInflater mInflater` and initialize it in your constructor:

```
mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```

In your ItemAdapter add this nested class:

```
public class ViewHolder {
    TextView name;
    TextView brand;
    TextView purchase_date;
}
```

In getView():

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder viewHolder;
    Item item = (Item) getItem(position);
    if(convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);

        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_item_name);
        viewHolder.brand = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_item_brand);
        viewHolder.purchase_date = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_purchase_date);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    }
    else
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

    viewHolder.name.setText(item.getName());
    viewHolder.brand.setText("[" + item.getItemType() + "] " + item.getBrand() + " " + item.getModel());
    viewHolder.purchase_date.setText(item.getPurchasedDateStr());
    return convertView;
}
```

Do you see how much less work happens if convertView has already been created? Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you so much @Sam. It's working now. I maked many revision on my codes. I changed my codes till getView method. I'll change it now.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't read everything but he stated filter method. So I would recommend [autoCompleteTextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html) as it does complete upon reaching a type of text available. As you press a letter lets say 'S' it will display samsungum or sony acd

Web Example:

```
public class CountriesActivity extends Activity {
     protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
         super.onCreate(icicle);
         setContentView(R.layout.countries);

         ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                 android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, COUNTRIES);
         AutoCompleteTextView textView = (AutoCompleteTextView)
                 findViewById(R.id.countries_list);
         textView.setAdapter(adapter);
     }

     private static final String[] COUNTRIES = new String[] {
         "Belgium", "France", "Italy", "Germany", "Spain"
     };
 }
```

Comment: Well my answer still stands. You can use a autocompletetextview and underneath will be a listview that displays the relevant information. The process will be a bit complicated as you have to create a new class that associates with autocompletetextview to lock the dropdown of names and then populate the listview.

Comment: I will try `autocompletetextview` thank you @Akyl . 
But my problem is different. When I press "s" key the all records gone. Something is happened. But I dont understand what happined background. But there is a fact. Filter methods doesn't work succesfully.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your `ItemAdapter` extend `ArrayAdapter` so you should create your custom filter. Check this [`SO question`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2718202/1050058) and  [another similar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2519317/1050058). In the first link there is another option is `override` toString in your `Item` class return the field you want to filter. Check by yourself. If you want to filter cursor adapter, follow Sam guide(in your posted code, you get data from cursor and put to your class so it not cursor adapter). Register your adapter with a `FilterQueryProvider` or return `filtered cursor` in [`runQueryOnBackgroundThread`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html#runQueryOnBackgroundThread%28java.lang.CharSequence%29)

Comment: Why should I create custom filter? This code is suitable for array adapter but not suitable cursor adapter.

Comment: Your `ItemAdapter` extend `ArrayAdapter`. I don't see any `cursor adapter`

Comment: But I'm using Cursor for getting record set. Is it a cursor adapter. I'm sorry @Yul, I don't know what it's differances between cursor and array adapter.

Comment: I'll try your sugestion, what is the best? FilterQueryProvider or runQueryOnBackgroundThread??

Comment: You only pull out a cursor and get data from it to your `Item` class. [Cursor Adapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html) is `adapter that exposes data from a Cursor to a ListView widget` .  About `FilterQueryProvider` and `runQueryOnBackgroundThread` are the same. I often use `runQueryOnBackgroundThread`. If you want to change your adapter to `Cursor Adapter`, here some [example1](http://developer.android.com/training/notepad/index.html), [example2](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/11/custom-cursoradapters/)