# MyArrayAdapter filterable?

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, android-filterable

I have a custom ArrayAdapter that extends ArrayAdapter:

```
class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> implements Filterable{
    Context context;
    String [] data;

    MyAdapter (Context context, String [] data) {
        super(context, R.layout.item_news, R.id.text, data);
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
    }

    class MyViewHolder {
        TextView text;

        MyViewHolder(View view) {
            text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        MyViewHolder myViewHolder = null;

        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mylayout, parent, false);
            myViewHolder = new MyViewHolder(row);
            row.setTag(myViewHolder);
        }
        else
            myViewHolder = (MyViewHolder) row.getTag();


        myViewHolder.text.setText(data[position]);
        return row;
    }
```

Now I want to let my Array Filterable. I tried with:

```
 Filter myFilter = new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
            ArrayList<String> tempList = new ArrayList<String>();

            if (constraint != null && data!= null) {
                String filterString = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
                for (int i=0; i< data.length; i++) {
                    String item = data[i];
                    if (item.toLowerCase().contains(filterString)) {
                        tempList.add(item);
                    }
                    filterResults.values = tempList;
                    filterResults.count = tempList.size();
                }
                return filterResults;
            }
            return null;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence contraint, FilterResults results) {
            data = (String[]) results.values;
            if (results.count > 0) {
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            } else {
                notifyDataSetInvalidated();
            }
            }
        };

        @Override
        public Filter getFilter() {
            return myFilter;
        }
```

but this doesn't works: when I call:

```
 adapter.getFilter().filter(filter);
```

no filter is applied. 
Can you please help me? I want to filter content by a string provided by the user.
PS if you find something wrong with my base adapter, please feel free to give me any suggest.

Answer (score 0):

There is a very details example on how to do this on [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2519317/how-to-write-a-custom-filter-for-listview-with-arrayadapter).
You are close, however, you have to use the Filtered list in your adapter, I would look at the link for more information.